# Calculating cummulative returns mid-year to mid-year Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe of the size (80219 * 5) with the same structure as the image I have uploaded. The data can range from 2002-2016 for each company but if missing values appear the data either starts at a later date or ends at an earlier date as you can see in the image.

What I would like to do is to calculate yearly compounded returns measured from June to June for each company. If there is no data for the specific company for the full 12 months period from June to June the result should be `nan`. Below is my current code, but I don't know how to calculate the returns from June to June.

After having loaded the file and cleaned it I:

```
df[['Returns']] = df[['Returns']].apply(pd.to_numeric)
df['Names Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Names Date'])
df['Returns'] = df['Returns']+ 1  
df = df[['Company Name','Returns','Names Date']]
df['year']=df['Names Date'].dt.year
df['cum_return'] = df.groupby(['Company Name','year']).cumprod() 
df = df.groupby(['Company Name','year']).nth(11)
print(tabulate(df, headers='firstrow', tablefmt='psql'))
```

Which calculates the annual return from 1st of january to 31st of december..

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to do it. The easiest way I could find is to calculate a rolling 12 month compounded return for each month and then slice the dataframe for to give me the 12 month returns of the months I want:

```
def myfunc(arr):
    return np.cumprod(arr)[-1]

cum_ret = pd.Series()
grouped = df.groupby('Company Name')
for name, group in grouped:
    cum_ret = cum_ret.append(pd.rolling_apply(group['Returns'],12,myfunc))
df['Cum returns'] = cum_ret
df = df.loc[df['Names Date'].dt.month==6]
df['Names Date'] = df['Names Date'].dt.year
```